# Getting segmentation fault core dumped error

Tags: c++

When I try to create the object of graph and pointer object of Edge it gives me segmentation fault while when I only create the graph object it does not gives me the error but when I create the graph object and Edge pointer object simultaneously it gives me the segmentation error. Why is it so? When I delete the line where the edge pointer object is declared in the main function then the code works fine but I need an edge object to display the edges...

The same code I run in any online c++ compiler gives me the correct output without any error.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class B>
struct Edge
{
    B vertex;
    Edge<B> *next;
};

template <class A>
struct VertexNode
{
    Edge<A> *edgeHead;
    A vertex;
    VertexNode *nextVertex;
};

template <class A>
class Graph
{
private:
    VertexNode<A> *head;

public:
    Graph();
    void insertVertex(A vertex);
    bool insertEdge(A vertex1, A vertex2); // this would return true if the both the vertices exists otherwise false
    bool deleteVertex(A vertex);           // this would return true if the vertex exists otherwise false
    bool deleteEdge(A vertex1, A vertex2); // this would return true if the both the vertices exists and the edge between them exists otherwise false
    bool isEmpty();
    Edge<A> *Adjacent(A vertex);
};

template <class A>
Graph<A>::Graph()
{
    head->edgeHead = NULL;
    head->nextVertex = NULL;
    head = NULL;
}

template <class A>
Edge<A> *Graph<A>::Adjacent(A vertex) // would return the list head of the edges
{
    for (VertexNode<A> *temp = head; temp != NULL; temp = temp->nextVertex)
    {
        if (temp->vertex == vertex)
        {
            return temp->edgeHead;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

template <class A>
bool Graph<A>::isEmpty()
{
    return (head == NULL);
}

int main()
{
    Graph<char> obj;
    Edge<char> *edgeHead; // for displaying the list of edges
    // adding vertices
    obj.insertVertex('A');
    obj.insertVertex('B');
    obj.insertVertex('C');
    obj.insertVertex('D');
    obj.insertVertex('E');
    obj.insertEdge('A', 'C');
    // now displaying adjacent edges for checking that our graph is implemented correctly
    edgeHead = obj.Adjacent('A');
}
```

Comment: This question's shown code does not meet stackoverflow.com's requirements for a [mre]. This means it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You should [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part) ***exactly as shown*** (this includes any ancillary information, like the input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: ***The same code I run in any online c++ compiler gives me the correct output without any error.*** That is a sign of undefined behavior.

Comment: I have updated the question @SamVarshavchik please review it again.

Comment: @ZainAhmad *The same code I run in any online c++ compiler gives me the correct output without any error.* -- This doesn't mean anything -- there are plenty of errors.  The problem is that a C++ program doesn't need to crash or show bad results for it to be wrong.  Be lucky that the program *did* crash -- now the errors are exposed and you get a chance to fix them.

Answer (score 2):

Removing unnecessary code, we get:

```
template <class A>
class Graph {
  VertexNode<A> *head;
  Graph();
};

template <class A> Graph<A>::Graph() {
  head->edgeHead = NULL;
  head->nextVertex = NULL;
  head = NULL;
}
```

At no point is memory allocated for head, so you are dereferencing an uninitialized value. That will often lead to a segmentation fault.